# Make similar function but exclude the last argument

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a type B which defines same function as type A but omits the last parameter. I've tried the following but it still asks for 2 parameters.

```
type Callback = (msg: string) => void;

type A = (A: string, B: Callback) => void;
type B = <U extends Exclude<Parameters<A>, Callback>>(...args: U) => void;

const b: B = (...args) => {};

b("some string"); // Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
```

How can I do this properly?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NavpEm) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: "It's a very simple code really I don't think it needs any more clarification." ‍♂️ Clarity is in the eye of the beholder. • Is your question "how do I do this" or "why is my approach not working"?  The latter is because `Exclude` filters unions, it does not truncate tuples.  Is that what you're asking?  • I'm not sure whether you're really looking to exclude that last parameter (which is what your words say) or exclude all elements that match a particular type (which is what your code looks like it's trying to do`).  Could you please [edit] to make the question more clear, if possible?

Comment: I only want to exclude the last element, It was actually part of a bigger function but I extracted it here to make it simpler. The code you sent is working correctly but I don't know how `infer` works. I should start googling

Comment: I will write up an answer explaining, and if you don't mind, I will [edit] your question to specifically ask "how do I do this" and not "why isn't mine working".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to exclude the last parameter from a function type:

```
type ExcludeLastParam<T extends (...args: any) => any> =
    T extends (...args: [...infer I, any]) => infer R ? (...args: I) => R : never;
```

This matches `T` against `(...args: [...I, any]) => R` for some `I` and `R` that the compiler infers using the `infer` keyword.  Note that `[...I, any]` is a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) and by matching `[...I, any]` against a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) (like, say, `[a: string, b: Callback]`), the compiler will infer `I` to be the "initial" part of the tuple excluding the last entry (since [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) will match anything) (like, say, `[a: string]`).

Let's test it out:

```
type Callback = (msg: string) => void;   
type A = (a: string, b: Callback) => void;

type B = ExcludeLastParam<A>;
// type B = (a: string) => void
```

And

```
type C = (a: string, b: number, c: boolean, d: Date) => string;
type D = ExcludeLastParam<C>
// type D = (a: string, b: number, c: boolean) => string
```

Looks good!

---

Note that your version doesn't work because, while [the `Parameters<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) can be used to extract the parameter list as a tuple type, [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) does not filter tuple types; instead it filters [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).  Since `Parameters<A>` is of type `[a: string, b: Callback]`, filtering out `Callback` isn't going to do anything (because `Parameters<A>` is not a union... or maybe it's a single member union, and that member is not assignable to `Callback`).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgGwQIzgYwNZQLxQBQC2AzgOYBcURwATgJYB2JAlDgHxQBuA9rQCYDcAKEGhIUAII58cClTqMANFGQV4SVJhbZ23PkJHhoAUQAeaBAFdeEADJwqABTjU4BADwAVKBBPAI9XiJ8ADpQ5xIiCjh6EC12aJB2bEEoVKgvHz8AoLxQ4PDIqABtPIYAMwhqKABJJQSAXTiocsqoACUoAH4QsOoIimqmjop6CA5K-VFoACEpU3MrW3tgJxd3cVYhAHotqCmoWdw8GUoaBmY2Th5eYTQueiplCkOe-L6iJoBvKABfIWQ8AAiIhcAjQOTnQFMfhQHZQUyQNB+XhQABMUHCFjB9GARCUyAswCgJC4RIAjMFhAYxDApMdZGdFE8oPQschKko0BRkFwuAgINElLwKAAROB+JoQxhCfYiuZmSzWOyOZyuNwwViCOGyuknKUkfEjNkcqBc5S8-nRSWMkhAA)